# How do I set the aliases to echo the commands before executing on Windows

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, alias

I am setting command line aliases on Windows using `doskey /MACROFILE=foo.txt`.

Before executing each command, I would like my command prompt to echo the actual command that I would be executing through aliases

My `set_aliases.bat` file looks like this:

```
DOSKEY /MACROFILE="foo.txt"
```

My `foo.txt` looks like this

```
cdhome=cd c:\
... 
other aliases that I want to set 
...
```

If I execute the `cdhome` command, I would like my command prompt to be doing this:

```
*** executing aliases: cd c:\ ***
```

before executing the command.

How would I achieve this on Windows?

Comment: First, understand what these aliases are. They aren't implemented by the CMD shell. By default doskey.exe creates aliases for CMD, i.e. it calls [`AddConsoleAlias`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/addconsolealias) with `ExeName` set to "cmd.exe". Console aliases substitute the alias target when the alias source string matches the beginning of a line when the console reads in line-input mode (i.e. [`ENABLE_LINE_INPUT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolemode)). The alias substitution has already occurred in a line of input that CMD read from the console.

Comment: This will probably help but has been a while. I checked an old file I have. You can do (from the command line) e.g. `doskey z=(echo abc ^& dir)`  so in a macros file  probably similar but without the word 'doskey'(you can experiment with escaping the ampersand or not).  And i think you can do in a macros file `z=blah.bat $*`   There can be whatever commands in that bat.